# Closing expressions in English Business Emails (GB/US)

Tags: communication, correspondence

So far I have seen several possible closing expressions to end your **business emails** with (assume I never wrote/talked to this person before). As I'm not a native speaker I'm not entirely sure about which of these is appropriate to be used in which context.

Which of the following are appropriate ways to end your business email:

- (with) regards
- (with) best regards
- (with) kind regards

Are some more formal than others?

I realize that this is highly specific to origin of the addressee, and might even be specific to certain industries. I'm interested in advice pertaining to contacts in the **US or GB**. (Should industry matter: assume **IT industry**, as in software engineering, technical consulting or the like).

Comment: You're overthinking things. Any of these is probably fine in almost all situations.

Comment: Nitpick: The "salutation" is the part at the beginning where you say "dear Mr. so-and-so". The part you're taking about is the "closing".

Comment: Good to know, fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list-based language question rather than being specific to navigating the workplace and as such is not a good fit for a Q&A site. There are plenty of resources available elsewhere for business-appropriate valedictions.

Answer (score 4):

Don't overthink this.

> Which of the following are appropriate ways to end your business email:

Most people won't care. Any of your examples are fine.

Best regards / With regards / Kind regards all convey the same idea. Pick one and put it in your email signature and don't worry.

> Are some more formal than others?

Perhaps "Best regards" is more formal. But you will find that everyone has different opinions on this, depending on all sorts of factors.

I would pick one (I personally use "Best regards"), put it in your email signature, and not worry about it.

If you are wanting to really figure out how your team feels about this, just ask some of your American/British colleagues their personal preferences. Most likely "Best regards" will be fine.

Comment: I tend to find the rough order of most to least formal is something like: Best regards -> regards -> kind regards -> best (regards) -> thanks -> cheers -> (name)